# in webtop 6.8.2, i had imported documentum with folder r_object_type mismatch what actually has to be

Tags: content-management-system, dql, documentum, webtop, documentum-dql

I have imported few documents, by creating a new folder, in webtop 6.8.2 patch 9, having wrong "r_object_type" which cause access will not be updated for users. Thus, I updated "r_object_type" using API script which causes sub-folders to get detached from parent one and goes to root but folder structure we can in read-only.

Now, I have deleted all sub-folders using API script and want to delete parent folder, but it is giving error as r_object_id does not exist. Also, i cannot create any sub-folders under this parent-id.

Please suggest how to delete the parent folder in Documentum.

Comment: so as per my understanding, you created a new folder(lets say folder "abc"), but with a wrong "object type", and uploaded the documents in it. However due to wrong object type of this folder, the access is not updated on the documents inside this folder. 
Then you have tried to change object type of the folder "abc" using API, due to this all the subfolders of "abc" are attached to the root folder now(cabinet).

Also you are not able to delete any of the subfolder, neither are able to create any folder inside "abc", correct?

Comment: Hi Vineet, just to update, i am able to delete sub-folders which anyway i am getting it while searching by folder name , but not able to open parent folder ,neither i am able to dump and destroy using API script after deleting all subfolders, not upload any documents by creating a new folders in it.

Comment: I tried to fetch path and got error:
API> getpath,c,0b004d0680b5axxx
...
[DM_API_E_EXIST]error:  "Document/object specified by 0b004d0680b5axxx does not exist."

[DM_SYSOBJECT_E_CANT_FETCH_INVALID_ID]error:  "Cannot fetch a sysobject - Invalid object ID 0b004d0680b5a985"

[DM_OBJ_MGR_E_FETCH_FAIL]error:  "attempt to fetch object with handle 0b004d0680b5axxx failed"

Comment: The object is pretty much corrupted:
1. By root( goes to root but folder structure we can in read-only.)  do you mean its visible under cabinet or somewhere else? 
2. also by read only, do you mean the folder is visible but neither opening nor deleting?